# Bracket Expected. But where?

Tags: java

I keep getting the error message ")" expected. I can not identify why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PartA extends ChangeDrawer
    {

       public static void main (String[] args)
       {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter P to make a purchase & receive your change");
            System.out.println("Enter L to load the Change drawer");
            System.out.println("Enter H to write the contents of the Change Drawer to a
            web Page");
            System.out.println("Enter E to exit the program"); //this is the user prompt

            String selection = input.nextLine();

           if{ //Error message: "(" expected

                (String selection=L)

                cDraw.loadFloat(floatDrawer);


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ( is a left parenthesis. When I hear "bracket" I think [ or {.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a condition in an `if` statement:

```
if(condition) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The entire condition is a bit messed up.

I think it's meant to be something like this:

```
if(selection.equals("L")) {
  cDraw.loadFloat(floatDrawer);
}
```